# Null space of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to find the basis of the null space of the matrix:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 5 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 & -2 \end{pmatrix} $$

I get the answer to be $\{[-3,1,-2]^T\}$ but Wolfram says the answer is $\{[3,-1,2]^T\}$

Who is right in this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are equivalent answers. Multiplying the answer Wolfram gave by $-1$ will give you the other vector. The null space is still a vector space, and so it is closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: Okay, so both are right, thank you.

Comment: More generally any two bases for a one-dimensional vector space (such as the null space of the rank 2 matrix in your problem) will consist of one vector in each, which are nonzero scalar multiples of each other.  So $\{[6,-2,4]^T\}$ is also a basis for the span of $\{[3,-1,2]^T\}$.